# I want to display the list of matching word, but just 1 result only

Tags: php, ajax, loops, for-loop, xmlhttprequest

I am doing the live search by XMLHttpRequest object. Javascript code is normal and works.

My php code is not good for the list of the matching results. (refer. last picture)

```
<?php
require './varmod/G.php';
require './varmod/g1.php';

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);

$hint = "";
echo "<ol>";

if ($q !== "") {
$q = strtolower($q);
$hint ="";

  for ($i=0;$i<count($G);$i++) {

      $x[$i] = $G[$i][0];
      **//Here is something wrong??**
    if (stristr($x[$i],$q)) { 
         if ($hint === "") { 
             $hint = $x[$i];
             echo  "<li><a href=\"https://medical- 
 dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/". $G[$i][1]."\">".$G[$i][1]."</a>-- 한글 : 
 <a href=\"https://www.google.com/search?q=\"".str_replace(" ","+",$G[$i][1]).   "&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUxfrjq9naAhUN5bwKHStsCWQQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=949\" target='_blank'> ".$G[$i][2]. "</a> --3D : <iframe
  id='embedded-human' frameBorder='0' width='600' height='450' allowFullScreen='true' src=\"".$G[$i][3]."\">3d</iframe</li>";
            } else {
                $hint = $x[$i];              
                echo  "<li><a href=\"https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/". $G[$i][1]."\">".$G[$i][1]."</a>-- 한글 : <a href=\"https://www.google.com/search?q=\"".str_replace(" ","+",$G[$i][0]). "&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUxfrjq9naAhUN5bwKHStsCWQQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=949\" target='_blank'> ".$G[$i][2]. "</a> --3D : <iframe
  id='embedded-human' frameBorder='0' width='600' height='450' allowFullScreen='true' src=\"".$G[$i][3]."\">3d</iframe</li>";
            }
        }
      }
     }
```

My ./varmod/G.php code is like as below

//3d names

```
$G=[
["Skeletal system","Skeletal system","골격계","https://human.biodigital.com/widget?be=2DNT&background=255,255,255,51,64,77&ui-cross-section=true&ui-dissect=true&ui-xray=true&uaid=2T5q8"],["Bones of head","Bones of head","머리뼈","https://human.biodigital.com/widget?be=2DNU&background=255,255,255,51,64,77&ui-cross-section=true&ui-dissect=true&ui-xray=true&uaid=2T5qK"],["Hyoid","Hyoid","설골","https://human.biodigital.com/widget?be=2F85&background=255,255,255,51,64,77&ui-cross-section=true&ui-dissect=true&ui-xray=true&uaid=2ThoY"],["Craniofacial bones","Craniofacial bones","두개안면뼈가","https://human.biodigital.com/widget?be=2DXR&background=255,255,255,51,64,77&ui-cross-section=true&ui-dissect=true&ui-xray=true&uaid=2T9mP"],["craniofacial bones","Right craniofacial bones","오른쪽두개안면뼈","https://human.biodigital.com/widget?be=2F86&background=255,255,255,51,64,77&ui-cross-section=true&ui-dissect=true&ui-xray=true&uaid=2Thoc"],["inferior nasal concha","Right inferior nasal concha","오른쪽하비갑개","https://human.biodigital.com/widget?be=2F88&background=255,255,255,51,64,77&ui-cross-section=true&ui-dissect=true&ui-xray=true&uaid=2Thol"],["lacrimal","Right lacrimal","오른쪽눈물","https://human.biodigital.com/widget?be=2F89&background=255,255,255,51,64,77&ui-cross-section=true&ui-dissect=true&ui-xray=true&uaid=2Thop"],...
```

[image]

I want to show many results, but just 1 result only. 
I want this picture as below.
[image]
Please, give me a piece of advice.
Thank you for your concern.

Comment: `My php code is not good for the list of the matching results.`-> and what is not good there? Please explain your problem

Comment: Yeah, i edit. I want to show many results, but just 1 result only. Please, give me a piece of advice. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: `I want to show many results, but just 1 result only.`-> confusing?

Comment: "*`str_replace(" ","+",$G[$i][1])`*" replacing a space with a plus sign is only for legacy support. Use `%20` instead or simply `rawurlencode($G[$i][1])`.

Comment: can you dump the $G variable?

Comment: Impossible. That memory is about above 30M. That is composed of nested array.